# Error in "proof" that $l^1$ and $l^2$-summability of $\hat{f}$ implies $L^4$-integrability of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

I have written a proof which seems to imply that a function is $L^4$-integrable over $[0, 2\pi]$ if its Fourier coefficients are $l^1$ and $l^2$-summable over $\mathbb{Z}$. I don't think this is correct. Where am I going wrong in my argument?

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ belongs to both $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, and that $\hat{f}(0) = 0$. Using Parseval's identity, we have:

$$\displaystyle \|f\|_{4}^{4} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(x)|^{4} \ \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(x)^2|^2 \ \mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f(n)^2}|^2 = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|\widehat{f(n)^2}|^2 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|\widehat{f(-n)^2}|^2 \\ = \|\widehat{f(n)^2}\|_{l^2}^2 + \|\widehat{f(-n)^2}\|_{l^2}^2$$

(There is a factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in there also, but I left that out for ease of notation.) Now, the convolution theorem says that $\widehat{f\cdot g} = \hat{f} \ast \hat{g},$ where $\ast$ denotes the discrete convolution. Further, Young's inequality says that $\|x \ast y\|_{l^r} \leqslant \|x\|_{l^p} \cdot \|y\|_{l^q},$ where $x \in l^p$ and $y \in l^q$ with $1/p + 1/q = 1/r + 1$, $p,q,r \in [1,\infty].$ Therefore, setting $p = 1, q = 2, r = 2$, we have:

$$\displaystyle \|\widehat{f(n)^2}\|_{l^2}^2 + \|\widehat{f(-n)^2}\|_{l_2}^2 = \|(\hat{f} \ast \hat{f})(n)\|_{l^2}^2 + \|(\hat{f} \ast \hat{f})(-n)\|_{l^2}^2 \\ \leqslant \|\hat{f}(n)\|_{l^1}^2 \cdot \|\hat{f}(n)\|_{l^2}^2 + \|\hat{f}(-n)\|_{l^1}^2 \cdot \|\hat{f}(-n)\|_{l^2}^2 < \infty.$$

I am sure I must be doing something wrong. Could someone help me see what it is?

Comment: The Fourier coefficients $(c_n) \in l^1$  means that the Fourier series converges absolutely, i.e. $f_N(x) = \sum_{|n| < N} c_n e^{inx}$ (a sequence of continuous functions) converges uniformly to $f(x) =\sum_{n} c_n e^{inx}$ so that $f(x)$ is continuous and $f \in L^p([0,2\pi])$ for every $p$.

Comment: @Yongyong There are multiple versions of the convolution theorem -- the one you stated is the usual one, but I am using another version: see the second formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

Comment: assuming everything is $\ge 0$ and I made no mistakes : $f \ast g(n) = \sum_k f(k) g(n-k)$ then $\|f \ast g\|_{l^2}^2 = \sum_n (\sum_k f(k) g(n-k))^2 =\sum_n \sum_k f(k) g(n-k)\sum_l f(l) g(n-l)$ $ = \sum_n \sum_k \sum_l f(k) g(n-k) f(l) g(n-l) <  \sum_k \sum_l f(k)  f(l) (\sum_n g(n-l)g(n-k))$ $ \sum_k \sum_l f(k) f(l) \|g\|_{l^2}^2 < \|g\|_{l^2}^2 \|f\|_{l^1}^2$

Comment: So I agree with the formula you obtain (up to the factor $1/(2\pi)$ that you forgot in the $2\pi$ periodic Parseval theorem)

Comment: sorry for my mistake. but now I have the question: the condition for Parseval's identity is that the function should be square intergrable. But $f^2$ is just of class $l^1$, so in general the condition is not fulfilled.